# renaming jsf.js.jsf to jsf.js.xhtml

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

The xhtml pages contain

```
<script src="/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.jsf?ln=javax.faces&amp;stage=Development" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If I remove the scripts the javascript functions do not work as expected. 
The requirement is to support only .xhtml pages. So, I went ahead and removed servlet-mapping for .jsf in web.xml, which results in javascript functions being executed incorrectly.

So, can we change jsf.js.jsf to jsf.js.xhtml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be done automatically if you're properly using `<h:head>` instead of `<head>`. You should not manually include the `jsf.js` in a `<script>` at all. Fix the `<head>` in your master template to be `<h:head>` and remove all those `<script>` lines referring `jsf.js` from your Facelet templates.

Comment: The <h:head> tag is added correctly. But if we remove the jsf.js script include, the JavaScript is not functioning correctly.

Comment: Then your problem is caused elsewhere. Start debugging the HTTP traffic and JavaScript environment in the webbrowser.