# jsf.ajax.addOnEvent works only if I explicitly include javax.faces:jsf.js

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2.2

I am using JSF 2.2.4 with the following in head tag:

```
<h:outputScript library="javax.faces" name="jsf.js" />
```

Later I found following post and removed the above code as it will be included automatically:
[renaming jsf.js.jsf to jsf.js.xhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368362/renaming-jsf-js-jsf-to-jsf-js-xhtml)

When I checked found that it is included automatically as said but we are getting error with a script that is put in the head of common template. The error is the script is getting the **object jsf** as **undefined**. The purpose of this script is to show a common loader for all JSF AJAX calls. The script is given below:

```
//To display loading indicator for all JSF f:ajax calls.
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
  var ajaxstatus = data.status; // Can be "begin", "complete" and "success"
  switch (ajaxstatus) {
    case "begin": // This is called right before ajax request is been sent.
      wizShowAjaxLoader();
      break;
    case "complete": // This is called right after ajax response is received.
      wizHideAjaxLoader();
      break;
    case "success": // This is called when ajax response is successfully processed.
      // NOOP.
      break;
  }
});
```

I wonder why it is working when I explicitly include jsf.js. When I remove this, script is showing jsf object as undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that your script is invoked **after** `javax.faces:jsf.js` is being included, for the very simple reason that `jsf` is only defined in JavaScript scope when the `javax.faces:jsf.js` has been included (and executed).

In a nutshell, you need to make sure that the JavaScript code flow is like below:

```js
var jsf = ...;
...
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(...);
```

And thus not like so:

```js
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(...);
...
var jsf = ...;
```

One way of ensuring this is to include your script as `<h:outputScript>` in `<h:body>` with the `target` set to `head`.

```xml
<h:head>
    ...
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputScript name="yourscript.js" target="head" />
    ...
</h:body>
```

JSF will ensure that it ends up in HTML head **after** the auto-included scripts.

An alternative is to keep it in `<h:head>`, but set `target` to `body`.

```xml
<h:head>
    ...
    <h:outputScript name="yourscript.js" target="body" />
</h:head>
```

JSF will ensure that it ends up in very end of HTML body, so that it's basically executed right before DOM loaded event.

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template/)

Comment: If so, I wonder why it is not showing any error when I move the loader display script from head to bottom of body. When I inspected with firebug, jsf.js is called on the page load.

Comment: You didn't state that anywhere in the question. I'll update the answer.